# Adding System.windows.Forms reference into asp.net website

Tags: asp.net, .net, winforms

I have a asp.net application where i use System.Windows.Forms namespace reference to use web browser control.the application runs fine on local system but after hosting it shows error.
How do i embed the dll for to use in the web application.

Comment: You can't do this. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Are you just looking for another web window on your web page?

Comment: How were you anticipating using a web browser within a server-side application?

Comment: Hi @JonSkeet, you can use the web browser to make screenshots for thumbnails/previews. As far as I can see this is the only native way to do it within the .NET framework.

Comment: @DirkBower: Assuming that's for testing, I wouldn't put that into the web application itself. Unfortunately the OP never got back to us about what they were trying to do.

Comment: @DirkBoer: (And if it's not for testing, that sounds like it's probably a bad idea. I wouldn't want a web browser running possibly dubious code on my server.) Apologies for the typo in your name earlier, btw - the perils of using a mobile with no autocomplete for @ comments.

Comment: Hi @JonSkeet, can't answer for the OP, but I hit the same problem. I am using it within a web application atm - and it *does* feel quite dirty, but I haven't found another way yet. Would still be a good idea to make this a separate microservice. About the dubious code, shouldn't such a webcontrol be hardcore sandboxed? Or am I missing some other vulnerability?

Comment: @DirkBoer: I wouldn't want to assume anything about how well sand-boxed the control is. But if you want it to look how a web page would actually look, that will involve running Javascript, and I wouldn't personally want to do that on a server without it being *very* carefully controlled. (For example, you'd want to give it a very small amount of CPU to use before killing it.)

Comment: Hi Jon, thanks a lot. Good point, unnecessary risk. I see if I can move it to a fully sandboxed (stateless) microservice that has no access to any resources.

Answer (score 2):

Answering a 3 1/2 year old question is pretty weird...

**I. In your web.config, add a reference to Windows.Forms**

```
<system.web>
  <compilation>
    <assemblies>
      <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
    </assemblies>
  </compilation>
<system.web>
```

*This only works if the referenced DLL is in the GAC.* If it is not:

1. Create a `/Bin` folder in your website root.
2. Copy your DLL there.
3. Do ***not*** add a reference in web.config.

**II. In your module/class, import Windows.Forms (VB: Imports / C#: using)**

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms
```

You can now use the web browser control. It's a bit tricky, though.

Possible uses include: generating screenshots, AJAX crawling (#! >> _escaped_fragment_) etc

Answer (score 0):

`System.Windows.Forms` contains classes for displaying things on the computer that the code is running on. When you are testing on your PC, it works because you run the browser on the same machine as your development server.

When running on a real server, anything in `System.Windows.Forms` would be displayed on the server - not on the user's PC. (Besides it would be displayed on a hidden desktop in the server's service session).

You shouldn't mix webforms and windows forms. Whatever you want to do - there is another way that works, that doesn't involve winforms.

#### Don't use `System.Windows.Forms` in webb applications

Answer (score 0):

As previously mentioned, you cannot use WinForms controls with ASP.NET.

Use an iframe to show whatever page you're trying to display in the webbrowser control: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can do it,just copy the

> system.window.form

dll into your web Bin Folder 
everything will work fine.