# AutoCompleteStringCollection could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I am using [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/243368/AutoComplete-Textbox) translated into C# so I have the following codepart:

```
List<string> lst = new List<string>();

        //AutoComplete collection that will help to filter keep the records.
        AutoCompleteStringCollection MySource = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
```

I get an error for AutoCompleteStringCollection saying:

> Error 1   The type or namespace name 'AutoCompleteStringCollection' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I have alrdeady included

```
Using System.Windows.Forms;
```

I have also added a reference to the Integration dll file.

which is where this class should normally be.

Any ideas?

Comment: you should add a reference to the dll,but its generally not a good idea to use winforms lib on asp.net app. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10850495/adding-system-windows-forms-reference-into-asp-net-website

Comment: @CodeIgnoto ok thx for the clarification ;) I'll try to work around windows forms then. Oh and btw I have already added a refenence to it and solved some other problems that I had but not this one. Still does not recognize it